# Sleep php no funciona en hosting online

Tags: php, modal, hosting

Estoy haciendo un loading mediante un modal-box ejecutando una secuencia de ajax.

el código del modal-box es el siguiente:

```
<a id="myBtn" href="#openModal"><button type="button" name="submit2" id="submit2" class="button"><span>Submit</span></button></a>

 <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
              <div class="loadmin" id="load"> 
                <div class="flex loading"> <button id="loading_icon"></button >
                <h2>Loading...</h2> </div>
              </div>
     </div>
```

y la ejecución del ajax el siguiente:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#submit2").click(function() {   
                $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: 'ajax/loading.php',
                      beforeSend: function() {
                         $("#load").fadeIn('fast');},
                    success: function(data) {
                         if(data == 1){ $("#matching").submit(); }
                    }
                })
            })
    })
</script>
```

y el archivo loading.php al que hace referencia el ajax es el siguiente:

```
<?php 
    set_time_limit(0);

    sleep(3);

    //start again
    echo ("1");
?>
```

Ejecutantolo en localhost con wampserver el sleep del loading.php funciona perfectamente hay una pausa de 3 segundos mostrando el cartel de loading antes de hacer el submit.

Pero el problema es cuando lo subo a un hosting online, el sleep no respecta la pausa de 3 segundos y se ejecuta muy rápido se aprecia que sale un cartel pero en seguida desaparece casi ni da tiempo a leer loading.

¿Alguien sabe decirme que es lo que esta ocurriendo.?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontré lo que ocurría, el hosting tiene desactivada la función sleep, por lo tanto lo he cambiado por la función usleep y ahora si que funciona.

Saludos.